# How to use ResourceDictionary as StaticResource in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary, valueconverter

I have a Windows Phone 7 app which I'm trying to create a Windows Phone 8 version of it.

In the app I have a ResourceDictionary defined in a XAML file as:

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:String x:Key="AppName">My App Name</sys:String>
    <!-- etc. -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This ResourceDictionary is referenced in App.xaml as:

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Constants.xaml"/>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then the easy part of doing:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}"/>
```

The above works perfectly fine with Windows Phone 7, however, in Windows Phone 8 there is an additional `Application.Resources` item which is `<myNamespace:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>` which when I have my app does not compile as it complains about

> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

So I changed by code to be:

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <myNamespace:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MainDictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Constants.xaml"/>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I have another problem. My app compiles but when it runs it throws a `XamlParseException`:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AppName

This all happens because of `LocalizedStrings` resource. Can someone help in making that work?

By the way, I have the same issue with the Value Converters; if they are done differently I appreciate if someone can help in that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, was having the exact problem myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the localized strings entry into the top-level application resource dictionary.

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MainDictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Constants.xaml"/>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <myNamespace:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: i have the same problem but this recommendation doesn't solved my problem, i have did same and many more but error never gone

Answer (score 0):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Constants.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? As the code you suggest doesn't work as is.

Comment: The code is correct as it is, and it works perfectly fine here. Clearly you're having other issues, than what you're describing.

Comment: I have corrected my question. Looks like that problem exists as long as `<myNamespace:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>` exists.